# Angular async validator map vs tap different results

Tags: angular

I wrote a demo for You: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ce8a6z) to make it simple.

Here is the situation I got:

[image]

```
MAP: false
TAP: false
```

Now here comes the question:

Why there is a difference in the behaviour of async validators depending of rxjs oprator used?

- if `map` is used everything seems to be ok: input is valid if valid, invalid otherwise
- if `tap` is used input is not relevant and only sync validator is take into the account.

My question is: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tap()` and `map()` are two entirely different operators. They are not interchangeable.

[map()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) will use the function you provide in its parameter to change the value of an observable from one thing, to another.

[tap()](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) runs a *side-effect*. I won't go too deep into [what a side-effect is](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) but in short it's something that doesn't have to do with a function's return value.

In your code:

```js
  static dummyTap(isValid: () => boolean): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      console.log("TAP " + isValid());
      return of(isValid).pipe(
        tap(() => isValid() ? null : {invalid: true})
      );
    };
  }
```

The `tap()` here does nothing. `tap()` has no effect on the return value of the pipe it is in.

I've forked the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-84vdbr) with some extra logging to try to demonstrate that point.